# Convert two collections of different objects into a single collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am combining two lists of separate objects into a single combined list. The below code works perfectly but it is not the most elegant or efficient solution. Is there a better solution?

```
var articles = context.Articles.Where(a => a.Author.ID == authorID).ToList();
var reviews = context.Reviews.Where(a => a.Author.ID == authorID).ToList();

var items = articles.ConvertAll(x => new ItemViewModel(x.ID, x.Title, x.Summary, "article", x.PublishDate)).Union(reviews.ConvertAll(r => new ItemViewModel(r.ID, r.Title, r.Summary, "review", r.PublishDate))).Take(20).OrderByDescending(i => i.publishDate);
```

Comment: Your title says "collection of two objects". Do you mean "two collections of objects"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with some sensible line continuation and indentation so we can see what's actually going on here.

```
var articles = context.Articles.Where(a => a.Author.ID == authorID).ToList();
var reviews = context.Reviews.Where(a => a.Author.ID == authorID).ToList();

var items = articles.ConvertAll(x => new ItemViewModel(x.ID, x.Title, x.Summary, "article", x.PublishDate))
    .Union(reviews.ConvertAll(r => new ItemViewModel(r.ID, r.Title, r.Summary, "review", r.PublishDate))
    ).Take(20)
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.publishDate));
```

Not perfect, but better. Remember, it's not necessary to cram all those lambdas onto a single line.

Is there a reason you're calling `ToList()`? That forces the execution of the query. If this is hitting a database with a lot of records, that could be potentially expensive.

You could also potentially clean up the second query a bit by moving the "converts" to the the prior queries.

```
var articles = context.Articles.Where(a => a.Author.ID == authorID)
    .ConvertAll(x => new ItemViewModel(x.ID, x.Title, x.Summary, "article", x.PublishDate));

var reviews = context.Reviews.Where(a => a.Author.ID == authorID)
    .ConvertAll(r => new ItemViewModel(r.ID, r.Title, r.Summary, "review", r.PublishDate));

var items = articles.Union(reviews)
    .Take(20)
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.publishDate));
```

Which shows us a potential opportunity to extract a method to remove the duplication.

Lastly, are you sure this does what you intend it to do? You didn't tell us exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but usually I would want to sort the results prior to selecting the top x results. I can't recall off the top of my head which order of `Take` and `OrderBy` would produce the correct results, but you should definitely double check that you're getting the information that you think you are.

*You might need to work on the Union syntax a bit. I'm not sitting in front of my IDE, so I didn't try to compile it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I doubt the `ConvertAll` call would be understood by the underlying provider - +1 for the `Take` vs `OrderBy` though; if the first list has more than 20 items the result will only ever contain items from `articles` AFAIK.

Comment: Hi RubberDuck, 

As Matt says I convert to list to make use of convertall although you point out it is expensive.

You are completely correct on switching take and order by.

Comment: What about `.Select(x => new Foo(x.Bar, ...))`? I'm not sure exactly how it'd be different from `ConvertAll`.